# Angular(HTML5) with DotNet (rewrite config), For Seo, Read Whole URL

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, url-rewriting, phantomjs

I'm using angularJS and C#,
Due to my superior demand, i have to use HTML5 mode at all cost, mean no '#' sign.
And Again do to his request, i Used rewrite to provide ability to access the angular page even on page refresh.
Recently we implement phantomJS, the first page did worked well, till i notice other page doesn't, after digin-in in codes, i found out that, NO, it wont capture the whole URL, for example, for: `http://localhost:xyzw/flights?_escaped_fragment_=` it only capture the `http://localhost:1350/?_escaped_fragment_=`, which doesn't contain the 'flights' part. i also made some change in my rewrite config, which the last one was adding following rule to ignore these path for angular app, and process them directly: `<add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />`

I separate my code for those who come and say hey shorten your issue, as whole of it can be,...

- first part, my configs and small codes
- second the tutorial i read about PhantomeJS
- other files which may be required

**Here are my main setup:**

WebConfig Rewrite:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!--<rule name="Seo rewrite rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="http://service.prerender.io/http://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
    </rule>-->
    <rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Token" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/bundles/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Content/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Scripts/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/SiteMap/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/CallBackBank/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Error/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/HtmlSnapshot[^s]?/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Flight[^s]?/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Hotel[^s]?/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Tour[^s]?/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/TravelAgency[^s]?/" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Users[^s]?/" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Phantom JS required Filter:

```
public class AjaxCrawlableAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string Fragment = "_escaped_fragment_";
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var url = request.Url.ToString();
        if (request.QueryString[Fragment] != null && !url.Contains("HtmlSnapshot/returnHTML"))
        {
            url = url.Replace("?_escaped_fragment_=", string.Empty).Replace(request.Url.Scheme + "://", string.Empty);
            url = url.Split(':')[1];
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
               new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "HtmlSnapshot" }, { "action", "returnHTML" }, { "url", url } });
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

Route Config:

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.LowercaseUrls = true;

        //PhantomJS
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HtmlSnapshot",
            url: "HtmlSnapshot/returnHTML/{*url}",
            defaults: new {controller = "HtmlSnapshot", action = "returnHTML", url = UrlParameter.Optional});
        ////PhantomJS
        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "SPA",
        //    url: "{*catchall}",
        //    defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index"});

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional});
    }
```

**PhantomJS for C#** The tutorial that i read:
OK, since the tutorial i read about phantomjs is in non-english i post the thing i wrote for my later usage:

1.Install Package

```
Install-Package PhantomJS.exe -version 1.9.2.1
```

2.Create Helper

```
public class AjaxCrawlableAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.ActionFilterAttribute
{
    private const string Fragment = "_escaped_fragment_";
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        var url = request.Url.ToString();
        if (request.QueryString[Fragment] != null && !url.Contains("HtmlSnapshot/returnHTML"))
        {
            url = url.Replace("?_escaped_fragment_=", string.Empty).Replace(request.Url.Scheme + "://", string.Empty);
            url = url.Split(':')[1];
            filterContext.Result = new RedirectToRouteResult(
               new RouteValueDictionary { { "controller", "HtmlSnapshot" }, { "action", "returnHTML" }, { "url", url } });
        }
        return;
    }
}
```

3.Replace Default Routes With:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "HtmlSnapshot",
            url: "HtmlSnapshot/returnHTML/{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "HtmlSnapshot", action = "returnHTML", url = UrlParameter.Optional });

        //If doesn't work, use default route instead...:
        routes.MapRoute(
        name: "SPA",
        url: "{*catchall}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
    }
```

4.Add AjaxCrawlableAttribute As A Filter

```
public class FilterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new AjaxCrawlableAttribute());
    }
}
```

5.Create HtmlSnapshot Controller

```
public ActionResult returnHTML(string url)
    {
        var prefix = HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme + "://" + HttpContext.Request.Url.Host + ":";
            url = prefix + url;
            string appRoot = Path.GetDirectoryName(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory);
            var startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
            {
                Arguments = string.Format("{0} {1}", "\"" + Path.Combine(appRoot, "Scripts\\seo.js") + "\"", url),
                FileName = "\"" + Path.Combine(appRoot, "bin\\phantomjs.exe") + "\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            CreateNoWindow = true,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            RedirectStandardError = true,
            RedirectStandardInput = true,
            StandardOutputEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8
        };
        var p = new Process();
        p.StartInfo = startInfo;
        p.Start();
        string output1 = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
        p.WaitForExit();
        var removeNgUiView = output1.Replace("<!-- ngView:  -->", "").Replace("ng-view=\"\"", "");
        removeNgUiView = Regex.Replace(removeNgUiView, "<!--\\suiView:\\s\\w*\\s-->", "");
        removeNgUiView = Regex.Replace(removeNgUiView, "(<\\w+[^>]*)(ui-view(=\"\\w*\")?)([^<]*>)", "$1$4");
        removeNgUiView = Regex.Replace(removeNgUiView, "(<\\w+[^>]*)(ng-app(=\"\\w*\")?)([^<]*>)", "$1$4");
        ViewData["result"] = removeNgUiView;
        return View();
    }
```

6.Create Views of Controller

```
@{
    Layout = null;
}
@Html.Raw(ViewData["result"])
```

7.Create seo.js in Script (!Important) Folder

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
    var system = require('system');

    var lastReceived = new Date().getTime();
    var requestCount = 0;
    var responseCount = 0;
    var requestIds = [];
    var startTime = new Date().getTime();;
    page.onResourceReceived = function (response) {
        if (requestIds.indexOf(response.id) !== -1) {
            lastReceived = new Date().getTime();
            responseCount++;
            requestIds[requestIds.indexOf(response.id)] = null;
        }
    };
    page.onResourceRequested = function (request) {
        if (requestIds.indexOf(request.id) === -1) {
            requestIds.push(request.id);
            requestCount++;
        }
    };

    function checkLoaded() {
        return page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.all["compositionComplete"];
        }) != null;
    }
    // Open the page
    page.open(system.args[1], function () {

    });

    var checkComplete = function () {
        // We don't allow it to take longer than 5 seconds but
        // don't return until all requests are finished
        if ((new Date().getTime() - lastReceived > 300 && requestCount === responseCount) || new Date().getTime() - startTime > 10000 || checkLoaded()) {
            clearInterval(checkCompleteInterval);
            console.log(page.content);
            phantom.exit();
        }
    }
    // Let us check to see if the page is finished rendering
    var checkCompleteInterval = setInterval(checkComplete, 300);
```

8.Layout.cshtml Based On:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="appOne">
<head>
    <meta name="fragment" content="!">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link href="~/favicon.ico" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <base href="/">
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/angular/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script>
        angular.module('appOne', ['ngRoute'], function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
            $routeProvider.when('/one', {
                template: "<div>one</div>", controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            })
            .when('/two', {
                template: "<div>two</div>", controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            }).when('/', {
                template: "<div>home</div>", controller: function ($scope) {
                }
            });
            $locationProvider.html5Mode({
                enabled: true
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="body">
        <section ng-view></section>
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
    <div id="footer">
        <ul class='xoxo blogroll'>
            <li><a href="one">one</a></li>
            <li><a href="two">two</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

NOTE: PhantomJS cannot process Persian Links(UTF-8)

**Third part, other things you may required to know**...
I don't see any other thing that may be involved, if you saw one ask me i'll edit my question.

Comment: To Moderator, Can i have ability to add an article to phantomjs section, regarding this matter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what i did:

for configuration:

```
<rule name="Crawler" stopProcessing="false">
  <match url=".*"/> <!-- rule back-reference is captured here -->
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="(.*)_escaped_fragment_=(.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" /><!-- condition back-reference is captured here -->
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:0}" /><!-- rewrite action uses back-references to condition and to rule when rewriting the url -->
</rule>
<rule name="Index Rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url=".*" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/api/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Token" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/bundles/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Content/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Scripts/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/SiteMap/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/CallBackBank/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Error/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/HtmlSnapshot[^s]?/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Flight[^s]?/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Hotel[^s]?/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Tour[^s]?/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/TravelAgency[^s]?/" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="^/Users[^s]?/" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

And here's for Filter:

```
var request = filterContext.RequestContext.HttpContext.Request;
        if (request.Url == null)
            return;
var url = request.Url.Scheme + "://" + request.Url.Authority + request.RawUrl; //THIS LINE (`RowUrl` contains rest of the path)
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a small article on it, just some simple settings, it is tested and working [see this](http://www.advancesharp.com/blog/1191/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-page-not-found-solution)

Add in your routing:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Index Page:

```
<base href="/">
```

And web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    ...........
</system.webServer>
```

You are done.

Comment: Rewrite alone work well, my issue is when i mix it with the tutorial cod that i talked about. then when i use crawler url (add `?_escaped_fragment_=`) it move only to first page of angular application, mean it's anable to read part of the path, or in that specific matter, it get redirected to the mail url, then passed to the phantomJS Handler (the hand writen code `AjaxCrawlableAttribute`).